# Reduction or atomic operator on unknown global array indices

Tags: c, cuda, atomic, reduction

I have the following algorithm:

```
__global__ void Update(int N, double* x, double* y, int* z, double* out)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < N)
    {
      x[i] += y[i];
      if (y[i] >= 0.)
        out[z[i]] += x[i];
      else
        out[z[i]] -= x[i];
    }
}
```

Important to note that out is smaller than x. Say x, y and z are always the same size, say 1000, and out is always smaller, say 100. z is the indices in out that each of x and y correspond to.

This is all find except the updates to out. There may be clashes across threads as z does not contain only unique values and has duplicates. Therefore I currently have this implemented with atomic versions of  [atomicAdd](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) and subtract using compare and swap. This is obviously expensive and means my kernel takes 5-10x longer to run.

I would like to reduce this however the only way I can think of doing this is for each thread to have its own version of out (which can be large, 10000+, X 10000+ threads). This would mean I set up 10000 double[10000] (perhaps in shared?) call my kernel, and then sum across these arrays, perhaps in another kernel. Surely there must be a more elegant way to do this?

It might be worth noting that x, y, z and out reside in global memory. As my kernel (I have others like this) is very simple I have not decided to copy across bits to shared (nvvp on the kernel shows equal computation and memory so I am thinking not much performance to be gained when adding overhead of moving data from global to shared and back again, any thoughts?).

Comment: What is this:  `out[i[z[i]]` ?  Did you mean `out[[z[i]]` ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella oops, sorry yes changed. z is an array of 'indices' to out. Each input element of x and y correspond to a different out via z. Added some more explanation I realised I didn't include sorry.

Comment: @James: That last comment isn't correct is it? Isn't the entire question premised on the problem that each element of x and y *don't* correspond to a different out via z? Otherwise the complexity of atomic operations is not required -- your kernel would  basically be a "fused add-scatter".

Comment: @talonmies yes you are right, my wording was bad. Each element of x and y are indexed via z in to out where there might be multiple elements of x and y that index to the same out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

1. Build a set of "transactions".  Since you only have one update per thread, you can easily build a fixed size "transaction" record, one entry per thread.  Suppose I have 8 threads (for simplicity of presentation) and some arbitrary number of entries in my `out` table.  Let's suppose my 8 threads wanted to do 8 transactions like this:

   ```
   thread ID (i):  0      1      2      3      5      6      7
   z[i]:           2      3      4      4      3      2      3
   x[i]:           1.5    0.5    1.0    0.5    0.1    -0.2   -0.1
   "transaction":  2,1.5  3,0.5  4,1.0  4,0.5  3,0.1  2,-0.2 3,-0.1
   ```
2. Now do a sort_by_key on the transactions, to arrange them in order of `z[i]`:

   ```
   sorted:         2,1.5  2,-0.2 3,0.5  3,-0.1 3,0.1  4,1.0  4,0.5
   ```
3. Now do a reduce_by_key operation on the transactions:

   ```
   keys:           2      3      4    
   values:         1.3    0.5    1.5
   ```
4. Now update `out[i]` according to the keys:

   ```
             out[2] += 1.3
             out[3] += 0.5
             out[4] += 1.5
   ```

[thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust) and/or [cub](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/) might be pre-built options for the sort and reduce operations.

Method 2:

As you say, you have arrays `x`, `y`, `z`, and `out` in global memory.  If you are going to use `z` which is a "mapping" repeatedly, you might want to rearrange (group) or sort your arrays in order of `z`:

```
    index (i): 0      1      2       3      4       5       6      7
         z[i]: 2      8      4       8      3       1       4      4
         x[i]: 0.2    0.4    0.3     0.1   -0.1    -0.4     0.0    1.0
```

group by z[i]:

```
    index (i): 0      1      2       3      4       5       6      7
         z[i]: 1      2      3       4      4       4       8      8
         x[i]:-0.4    0.2   -0.1     0.3    0.0     1.0     0.4    0.1
```

This, or some variant of it, would allow you to eliminate having to repeatedly do the sorting operation in method 1 (again, if you were using the same "mapping" vector repeatedly).

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella. I do indeed use the same mapping everytime so method 2 is probably more appropriate. In either case the sorting and reordering is going to happen on the host correct? My kernel will just return the one transaction (per thread) and the host will aggregate these and apply appropriately?

Comment: No, I was thinking of doing it all on the device.  If you were doing it in a single thread on the host, there wouldn't be any need for sorting (or atomics).

Comment: Hmm, ok, but two separate kernels? One as I launch above which returns one transaction per thread. Then another kernel launch to take these transactions and add/subtract them appropriately? I think I am missing the point here sorry.

Comment: Yes, I could imagine 4 kernels or distinct operations if you followed method 1.  if you're trying to write 1000 values into 100 locations, we're pretty much wasting our time here.  If you're trying to write 1000000 values into 100000 locations, the overhead of 4 kernel launches isn't going to matter.

Comment: Thanks. So if (for simplicity) say `x`, `y` and `z` have size 1000, and `out` has size 100, step 1 is the same as my kernel except it places the transactions in `transaction` (size 1000). Step 2 is a second kernel which sorts these in order of `z` (I can impose presorted arrays so can skip this). Step 3 then has `transactions` size 1000, I'm not sure on the logic of this kernel to produce an output of size 100 without doing atomic as in my first example. Step 3 would then be a kernel of 100 threads adding these summed transactions?

Comment: step 3 is a reduce by key operation.  It is a segmented, parallel reduction.  It does not require atomics.  If you have 8 segments (8 distinct keys) then it's like performing 8 [parallel reductions](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/) simultaneously.  It's not trivial to code up (niether is a fast sort).  so I suggested the thrust and cub libraries, which are relatively high quality and fast.  I wouldn't suggest writing operations like parallel reductions and sorts by hand if you can reasonably avoid it.  Steps 1 and 4 are trivial (in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I agree 1 and 4 are easy. I shall look at step 3 (2 if needed) in thrust. It was an exercise of understanding more than just using already implemented libraries.